# Update status before delete yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem with yii update status before delete. I want to make the status of the product = 0 if the product is already set in order. Then if the product doesn't set in order, they will delete it.. Checking of the product is already set in order or not is doing well.. But when the program enter the (if($dorders>0)) it's not error, but the status of the product still 1.. didn't change to 0.. please help anyone.. thanks

```
public function actionDelete($id)
        {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->condition = 'id_product="'.$id.'"';
            $dorders=DOrder::model()->count($criteria);
            if($dorders>0){
                $model=$this->loadModel($id);
                $model->status=1;
                $model->save();
            }
            else{       
                $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
                unlink('uploads/product/'.$id.'.jpg');
            }

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check error messages:

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
$model->status=1;
$result = $model->save();

var_dump($result);
print_r($model->getErrors());
```

Comment: it works! it's because my silly fault.. thank you valery x_x.. hehe